# javascript implementation of newton vs. bisection

Tags: javascript, performance, numerical, newtons-method, bisection

Out of curiosity, I want to verify that Newton is indeed faster than 
bisection (for the cases it successfully converges) for solving nonlinear equations.

I implemented both out of `textbook algorithms`.
The function tested is:

```
 f(x) = 5*(x-0.4)*(x^2 - 5x + 10), with a simple real root 0.4
```

The convergence accuracy is set to 1e-4.
Newton starts at `x0 = 0.5`, `converges in 2 iterations`.
bisection starts with an `interval [0,1]`, converges in `14 iterations`.

I use `performance.now()` to measure the elapsed time of both methods.
SURPRISINGLY, with many tries, Newton is always slower than bisection.

```
Newton time: 0.265 msec: [0.39999999988110857,2]
bisection time: 0.145 msec: [0.399993896484375,14]
```

I ported the program to C (visual C): Newton is a lot faster than bisection.

These numerical codes are so simple that I cannot spot any weird thing going on.
Can anyone help?

http://jsfiddle.net/jmchen/8wvhzjmn/

```
// Horner method for degree-n polynomial
function eval (a, t) {

    // f(x) = a0+ a1x + ... + anxn
    var n = a.length - 1;// degree (n)
    var b = [];
    var c = [];
    var i, k;
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        b.push(0), c.push(0);

    b[n] = a[n];
    c[n] = b[n];
    for (k = n-1; k >= 1; k--) {
        b[k] = a[k] + t*b[k+1];
        c[k] = b[k] + t*c[k+1];
    }
    b[0] = a[0] + t*b[1];

    return [b[0],c[1]];
}

// simple Newton
function Newton (eval, x0, epsilon) {
    var eps = epsilon || 1e-4;
    var imax = 20;
    for (var i = 0; i < imax; i++) {
        var fdf = eval (coeff, x0);
        x1 = x0 - fdf[0]/fdf[1];
        if (Math.abs(x1 - x0) < eps)
            break;
        x0 = x1;
    }
    return [x1, i];  // return [approx. root, iterations]
}

// simple bisection
function bisection (func, interval, eps) {
    var xLo = interval[0];
    var xHi = interval[1];

    fHi = func(coeff,xHi)[0];   // fb
    fLo = func(coeff,xLo)[0];   // fa
    if (fLo * fHi > 0)
        return undefined;

    var xMid, fHi, fLo, fMid;
    var iter = 0;
    while (xHi - xLo > eps) {
        ++iter;
        xMid = (xLo+xHi)/2;
        fMid = func(coeff,xMid)[0];  // fc

        if (Math.abs(fMid) < eps)
            return [xMid, iter];

        else if (fMid*fLo < 0) { // fa*fc < 0 --> [a,c]
            xHi = xMid;
            fHi = fMid;
        } else {  // fc*fb < 0 --> [c,b]
            xLo = xMid;
            fLo = fMid;
        }
    }

    return [(xLo+xHi)/2, iter];
}

// f(x) = 5x^3 - 27x^2 + 60x - 20
//      = 5*(x-0.4)*(x^2 - 5x + 10)
var coeff = [-20,60,-27,5];  

var t0 = performance.now();
var sol1 = Newton (eval, 0.5, 1e-4);
var t1 = performance.now();
var sol0 = bisection (eval, [0,1], 1e-4);
var t2 = performance.now();

console.log ('Newton time: '+ (t1-t0).toFixed(3) +  ': ' + sol1);
console.log ('bisection time: '+ (t2-t1).toFixed(3) + ': ' + sol0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many external factors that can influence that test, including the order in which your code gets JIT compiled, and caching. Measuring time on such a small number of iterations isn't very meaningful, as those external factors may end up being bigger than what you're trying to measure.

For example, if you invert the order so it calculates bisection before it calculates Newton, you get the opposite result.

If you want to do it better, perhaps run both once, *then* do a loop to run both again N times, and measure how long it takes to run that loop.